# Reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level `jobs.*.uses' key, not within steps. Check current day of the week to run a git hub action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I tried with this in my GHA job.

```
jobs:
  bd_scan:
    steps:
      - name: Check Day of the Week
        id: check_day
        run: echo "::set-output name=day::$(date +%u)"
      - name: Run BD rapid scan
        if: ${{ steps.check_day.outputs.day < ‘5’ }} 
        uses: some-external-workflow-here
        with:
          GRADLE_BUILD: "no"
          NODE_BUILD: "no"
          RETRY: 3
        
    secrets: inherit
```

And got the below error -
`` reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level `jobs.*.uses' key, not within steps. ``
What change can I make here to check if the current day is Friday/ Saturday/ Sunday the stage should not run?

Comment: It's as the error says, you can't call reusable workflow within a job, the job itself is the reusable workflow. Check [this section of the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow) to understand how to call reusable workflows.

Comment: Regarding a workaround to achieve what you want. You can add the `day` output step in the own reusable workflow, or use 2 jobs, using the first one to extract the day, and the second one using the first job `day` output in the if expression.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for replying, yes I want to achieve all in one step.

```

jobs:

  bd_scan:

        if: ${{ (date +%u) < ‘5’ }} 

        uses: some-external-workflow-here

        with:

          GRADLE_BUILD: "no"

          NODE_BUILD: "no"

          RETRY: 3
        
    secrets: inherit

```

But this also did not work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as the error states, **you can't call reusable workflow within a job**, the job *itself* is the reusable workflow.

Check [this section of the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow) to understand how to call reusable workflows.

Example:

```yaml
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: OWNER/REPO/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
    secrets: inherit
```

---

In your case, thinking about an alternative, I see two options:

1. You could add the `day` output step in the own reusable workflow.
2. You could use 2 jobs, using the first one to extract the `day`, and the second one using the first job `day` output in an `if` expression.

Here is an example following the second option:

```yaml
jobs:
  bd_scan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      day: ${{ steps.check_day.outputs.day }}
    steps:
      - name: Check Day of the Week
        id: check_day
        run: |
          echo $(date +%u)
          echo "day=$(date +%u)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  
  reusable:
    needs: [bd_scan]
    if: ${{ needs.bd_scan.outputs.day < 5 }} 
    uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/reusable.yml@main
    with:
      day: ${{ needs.bd_scan.outputs.day }}
    secrets: inherit
```

*Note: The `::set-output` syntax [is not supported anymore](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) so I updated it to use GITHUB_OUTPUT instead.*

You can see a workflow run following this logic [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/6239354947/job/16937101242) where the workflow implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester89.yml).

Comment: Thanks for the greate explanation and taking time to resolve this.
I am now getting this error -
Invalid input, day is not defined in the referenced workflow.
The error is show in this line
day: ${{ needs.bd_scan.outputs.day }}
But I can also see it worked fine for you.

Comment: It may be related to the inputs configured in the reusable workflow (as you didn't check this part of the implementation in the question, I can't say how it is coded). But for what I understand, you won't need to send this input there, so you can still use `GRADLE_BUILD: "no"`, `NODE_BUILD: "no"` and `RETRY: 3`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was too dumb from my side, But thats for the useful links and to the point solution.